# Scala: implicitly converted type as implicit param of a method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have a method that expects some implicit param of type String.

I have an object of class `MyClass` which I want to pass to that method implicitly.
First, I'm making implicit conversion from `MyClass` to `String`.

If I pass object of `MyClass` to the method which expects `String` explicitly, it works fine.

But passing it implicitly causes compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter str: String someMethod()
```

Here is the code:

```
case class MyClass(str: String)
object MyClass {
  implicit def myClassToString(myClass: MyClass): String = myClass.str
}

object Application extends App {
  def someMethod()(implicit str: String) = println(str)
  implicit val myClass = MyClass("Hello")
  someMethod()(myClass) <-- WORKS
  someMethod() <-- ERROR
}
```

Is it possible to pass implicitly converted variable implicitly?

P.S.: **I cannot change someMethod**

Comment: Why won't you apply the conversion directly and have then implicit string in the scope without relying on the implicit conversion? `implicit val myClass: String = MyClass("Hello")`

Comment: someMethod is just for example. Actual method has more params and it is used in many places. So it would be a lot of code...

Comment: We shan't talk about the obvious nonsense of having `String` as type of an implicit parameter, shall we…

Comment: Allowing this would at least significantly increase compilation time by forcing the compiler to always check for such double conversions when it can't find an implicit. Scala already has problems there...

Answer (score 4):

It cannot work because you don't have an implicit String value. What you do have is an implicit conversion from `MyClass => String`, but not the string itself.

So what you need is to supply a String. Since you have the implicit conversion from MyClass to String, you can say:

```
def someMethod()(implicit str: String) = println(str)
implicit val myClass: String = MyClass("Hello") // conversion kicks in
someMethod() // error: no implicit string found in scope
```

This way in line 2 the implicit conversion kicks in, so by line 3 you have an implicit String ready to be passed in.

Note that if you keep the MyClass type, it can still work by explicitly providing the argument:

```
implicit val myClass: MyClass = MyClass("Hello")
someMethod(myClass)
```

So yeah, the line between what works and what doesn't seems a bit arbitrary. I'm not sure if it's caused by the amount of compiler hacks needed to make it work, or they simply wanted to prevent chaos from ensuing when doing such recursive implicit search. Probably the latter.

Comment: 1. I do not have a control of someMethod. 2. In your example, why I need  conversion at all if someMethod expects MyClass and I need to pass MyClass? I just could write def someMethod()(implict myClass: MyClass) = println(myclass.str)

Comment: Regarding 2), I was just making a point. `str` is an accidental convenience. But I get what you mean; see edited answer

Comment: As I mentioned in comment to my question, someMethod is just for example. Actual method has more params and it is used in many places. So it would be a lot of code... But you answered my question, it is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, there are strict rules regarding implicits and compiler searches for them in specific places in specific situations, otherwise it would be a mess. We are talking about a situation where `def foo(implicit bar: Bar)` followed by `foo()` compiles, and there are no implicit Bars in scope. Personally I would find that quite chaotic.